# Custom Principal in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, windows, asp.net-core, authentication

I currently have a web application running on .NET Framework 4.8.

Currently, Windows authorization information is converted into a custom principal in the `global.asax.cs` file like this:

```
protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Path.StartsWith("/ErrorHandler")) 
        return;

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Roles.Enabled)
    {
        CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(User.Identity);

        UserDto user = SecurityService.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("ErrorHandler/Unauthorized");
        }

        principal.UserId = user.UserId;
        principal.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
        principal.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        principal.LastName = user.LastName;

        Context.User = principal;
    }
}
```

I am about to migrate this program to .NET Core and I am wondering how to apply the above custom principal in my `Startup` file.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Using middleware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you could write a custom middleware to achieve you requirement.

More details, you could refer to below codes：

Please notice: You should put this middleware behind  `app.UseAuthentication();`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

    if (context.User.Identity != null)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();


            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", context.User.Identity.Name));

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            principal.AddIdentity(identity);

            context.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

Then check it inside the controller:

```
        var user = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "UserId").FirstOrDefault();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! You don't know how many hours I spent trying to ser the principal to a custom one, I really appreciate it!